# What is the best practice for an IONIC 2 app with lots of very similar pages

Tags: ionic2

I am working on an IONIC 2 app that have 60 pages (more or less). These pages are very similar to each other.

It is a questionnaires like app. There are 6 types of questions and each type of question has about 10 pages. Each page contains one question (and a 'next' button to go to the next page). The graphic designs and layouts on each page are similar.

I am unable to make a long scrollable page that contain multiple questions as pre requirement.

What I found, is the HTML file of these files are very similar and there are lots of duplicated codes. This is an issue as I have to go through all these pages if I want to change anything at all.

Is there any solution to address this code duplication problem?

Comment: The way I see it you have answered your own question. You need to create as many components/templates as the _number of types_. You could just set the same component _n_ times for _n_ different data.. So you would have 1 component for a page with "next" and 6 for types of questions.

Comment: from angular 2.3 component inheritance is possible. So that would be helpful in this scenario. https://scotch.io/tutorials/component-inheritance-in-angular-2